# Asian South West Monsoon - Rainfall in South East Coast of India

Tags: climate, wind, rain, monsoon

So Indian peninsula has v shaped mountain ranges. Western ghats and Eastern ghats as shown in the picture.

[image]

During Summer Monsoon, the wind flows from Indian ocean to land mass, and due to Coriolis force it bends right, and hits western ghats almost perpendicularly, and Kerala, Southern most west coast state gets orographic rain in windward side of the Western Ghats. The eastern coast however does not get rainfall, as the winds direction is parallel to eastern ghats.

[image]

I was wondering that if theoretically if we build artificial mountains (annotated in red), we should be able to get orographic rains along east coasts? I am not sure how much of the South West monsoon wind flows over the landmass of southern India and how moist it is?, as it is likely the western ghats block them significantly. Where and how can I find and interpret the wind data?

[image]

Comment: Not sure where you are headed with these ideas but already thought of and presented to Government - https://www.icts.res.in/sites/default/files/Krishnamurti_Cumulus_21_1_2013.pdf

Comment: Can you share page/slide number please? it is a pretty big document. I am not headed anywhere, was reading up about monsoon, and was wondering if it was theoretically plausible. But to figure that out on my own, I needed to fill my knowledge gaps about finding availability of monsoon wind in the landmass and its data

Comment: Just search for Jawadu Hills.

Comment: It seems like that they are trying to harness North East Monsoon? I am specifically looking for south west monsoon wind patterns over the Tamilnadu landmass

Comment: Similar idea to what you are proposing. Building walls over mountains to harness rainfall. Here is the full article - https://medcraveonline.com/IJH/IJH-01-00039

Comment: Thanks for validating the idea, which is part of the question. Also, do you know how to find summer monsoon wind data?

Comment: Yes go here - https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/composites/nssl/day/ and choose climataology and the data presents itself

Comment: @MichaelWalsby Is using the word 'God' permitted on a scientific site ? I have flagged it for moderator atention

Comment: @MichaelWalsby https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31966/to-what-extent-can-i-use-the-concept-of-god-in-a-meteorology-lecture-without-o